# Explanation of NSIncrementalStore in plain english

Tags: ios, web-services, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios5

I've been seeing `NSIncrementalStore` popping up as I've been researching the best ways to interact with a web service using core data.

After reading [an article by Drew Crawford](http://sealedabstract.com/code/nsincrementalstore-the-future-of-web-services-in-ios-mac-os-x/), [a programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/IncrementalStorePG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010706), [a class reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSIncrementalStore_Class/Reference/NSIncrementalStore.html) [and this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/1860108) a couple of times each I'm still struggling understanding what `NSIncremental` store is, why and when you would use it.

Could someone please explain it?

**Edit**
after reading mundi's answer I can see some further context is required. I'm looking into using core data in conjunction with a web service I am building. I am attempting to find the best way to store the users information locally on the device and post to web service when there is a connection. My lack of knowledge on core data prompted my research, but I was unable to fully comprehend the usefulness of `NSIncrementalStore`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*NOTE: this API was bleeding-edge when I wrote this in 2012 and details have changed. Feel free to update this if you wish. I'm not working on any Cocoa/ObjC projects at the moment so I am not a good person to keep this up-to-date, unfortunately. It does seem that the overall gist is correct.*

Core Data provides a set of tools that help manage object persistence, i.e. the ability to save and then fetch back sets of objects (`NSManagedObject`) from some kind of storage.

When you work with Core Data objects, you do so using an `NSManagedObjectContext`, which you get from an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. The PSC in turn talks to one or more `NSPersistentStore` subclasses, which handle the actual operations on the store. (Think create/read/update/delete against a database.)

Core Data supports two primary kinds of store: `NSPersistentStore` and `NSAtomicStore`. A persistent store can be thought of as a database: you can incrementally save, update and fetch arbitrary sets of records from it. An atomic store is an 'all or none' representation of an object graph. It is intended to be an in-memory representation of a structured file.

The store types that Core Data comes with are:

- `NSSQLLiteStoreType`  (`NSPersistentStore`)
- `NSInMemoryStoreType` (`NSPersistentStore`)
- `NSXMLStoreType`      (`NSAtomicStore`)
- `NSBinaryStoreType`   (`NSAtomicStore`)

`NSPersistentStore` is explicitly forbidden to be subclassed, so until now, there has been no way to create your own non-atomic store backend. That is, if you wanted to persist and query representations of your objects piecemeal as opposed to in one big lump ('load the entire graph', 'save the entire graph') you've been out of luck. Until iOS5 introduced `NSIncrementalStore`.

`NSIncrementalStore` is an abstract class (descended from `NSPersistentStore`) whose methods you implement to provide an adapter between a data store that you control and the world of Core Data. You can use it to wrap a remote API, or if you were so inclined you could wrap something like [NULevelDB](https://github.com/nulayer/NULevelDB) or [NanoStore](https://github.com/tciuro/NanoStore) (though I'm not sure why you'd do that).

Comment: I think you meant to say `NSIncrementalStore` and NSAtomicStore, not "`NSPersistentStore` [which is the base class] and NSAtomicStore".

Comment: Candidly I have no idea - I wrote this 4 years ago and haven't written any code for iOS in roughly a similar amount of time. Sorry!

Answer (score 9):

You would use `NSIncrementalStore` to access a remote server through Core Data. In stead of reading from and writing to a local file, you'd push request to the server and get a response back which you'd push into Core Data. Likewise for save, etc.

Note, however, that this is non-trivial to do. It's a very powerful feature, but unless you're an expert in Core Data usage, I'd strongly discourage it, since there are endless opportunities to shoot yourself in the foot unless you know a lot about how Core Data's interaction with the storage layer works.

If using an `uploaded` solves your problem, then do that instead.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that core data runs on the main thread and for core data to use this wouldn't that lock the main tread while the upload/download is running? Furthermore does it 'replace' the local sqlite db?

Comment: No. Core Data can run on any thread. It's not thread safe: You need to have one context per queue (or thread if you don't have GCD, yet). Just like anything else that's not thread safe.

Answer (score 5):

In a nutshell, if you use the SQLite store with your Core Data you are already using an incremental store. All the benefits of incremental stores (i.e. mainly not having to load the entire store into memory) are already at your disposal.

As for the concrete application of the `NSIncrementalStore` API, I would suggest that you first define exactly which problem you want to solve. If you require this API or not would be determined by the specific needs of your programming task.

---

**EDIT** in response to question edit

I would simply do it like this: In your Core Data entities on the device you can have an attribute `BOOL uploaded`. When the web service becomes available, start an upload and pull all the objects not `uploaded` yet.

To upload, transform your objects into `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, perhaps into JSON format and `POST` to your web site. When the web site responds that it saved the data, mark all the objects as `uploaded`.

Comment: That's a clever way to do it. I was thinking I might be able to use NSIncrementalStore to write to both the local db and try the web db. I will have to use a bit more of a complicated system than what you have outlined so that the device knows what to upload instead of everything. Thanks. I'm still open to suggestions and answers so I'll leave this unanswered for a while. Thanks

Comment: Well, I would not know why it has to be more complicated than what I outlined.

Comment: Because it would be cumbersome to upload the entire local structure. It is more efficient to upload the inserts, removes and updates. And to do that you would have to maintain that in your data structure. However I believe core data maintains that data before you run the save selector on your context. Do you have any recommendations with that in mind?

Comment: Sorry, it seems you did not read my answer carefully. You would only upload the records not uploaded yet. It is incremental, which is what you want. That's what the attribute `uploaded` would be intended for.

Comment: Ah i did misread, I thought you were implying an 'uploaded' attribute for all the entities, not one for each. This makes more sense but seems to couple the data structure and the uploading structure. I would prefer to avoid this reliance.

Comment: You could also keep a separate record of the entities to be uploaded, either also in core data or in some other form (it has to be persisted, though). Once uploaded, you can then delete these records.