# EGOPhotoViewer - Memory warning with many pictures iOS

Tags: ios, image, memory, warnings

I have a problem with the memory managment in [EGOPhotoViewer](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer). I get a memory warning after scroll about 50 pictures. In total, they have about 270 of them, each weighing approximately 100 kb and is different from others. I tried to resolve this problem by https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer/issues/6, but nothing helped.
Please help me, Pawel

//----- EDIT

Add further that all objects are properly released. In my opinion the problem is not removing images from the cache, but I don't know how to bite it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading all of them in the memory of course, and this is bad.

You need to use something like Core Data\NSIncrementalStore ([Explanation of NSIncrementalStore in plain english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459635/explanation-of-nsincrementalstore-in-plain-english)).

Another option is to use the NSUserDefaults, but this is a bad practice, as it is for storing user data only, but it gets the job done + it caches its data, for fast retrieval.

Need more help? I'm here ;D

Comment: I hope more specific guidance on how to correct the library EGOPhotoViewer than modify it in some way. Does anyone have any other suggestion?

Add further that all objects are properly released. In my opinion the problem is not removing images from the cache, but I don't know how to bite it...